# how to override a private property setter?

Tags: delphi

I have this (defined in delphi source code):

```
  TCanvasTextureMaterial = class(TCustomMaterial)
  private
    [Weak] FTexture: TTexture;
    procedure SetTexture(const Value: TTexture);
  protected
  public
    property Texture: TTexture read FTexture write SetTexture;
  end;
```

how to override the setter `SetTexture` in descendant class?

Comment: FWIW, in this case, it just sets FTexture. You can easily get the address of FTexture and do that yourself. Just do what Remy proposes. But it won't override what SetTexture does on a TCanvasTextureMaterial. In other words, you can't use inheritance (work "from the inside"), but there are other ways of changing behaviour (i.e. "from the outside").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### In short, you can't.

The setter is declared as `private` and thus is not accessible to descendants. But even if it were accessible, it is not declared as `virtual` so it can't be `override`'n anyway.

The only thing a descendant could do in this case is (re)declare its own property with its own setter (it could even reuse the same `Texture` property name), eg:

```
type
  TMyCanvasTextureMaterial = class(TCanvasTextureMaterial)
  private
    function GetMyTexture: TTexture;
    procedure SetMyTexture(const Value: TTexture);
  public
    property Texture: TTexture read GetTexture write SetMyTexture;
  end;
```

But, accessing the `Texture` property via a `TCanvasTextureMaterial` pointer will not call the descendant's setter, even if it does use the same property name:

```
var
  TM: TCanvasTextureMaterial;
begin
  TM := ...; // any TMyCanvasTextureMaterial object

  // reading from TM.Texture returns TCanvasTextureMaterial.FTexture,
  // it does not call TMyCanvasTextureMaterial.GetMyTexture()

  // assigning to TM.Texture calls TCanvasTextureMaterial.SetTexture(),
  // it does not call TMyCanvasTextureMaterial.SetMyTexture()
end;
```

Comment: a little addition: if the descendants SetMyTexture routine calls inherited, it will call the SetMyTextture of the base class, even when they are NOT declared in the same unit. The answer above is completely valid.

Comment: Except that there is no `SetMyTexture()` in the base class, it is `SetTexture()` instead, so the call would have to be like `inherited SetTexture(...);` instead. But in my example above, `SetMyTexture()` would not even be called.